# Keep a copy of some external variables when creating a function expression

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my first post. I hope I get everything across to you. I've searched extensively for a solution but I'm not really sure how to describe my problem.

This is a problem I've had numerous times for a few months since starting with JavaScript. Every time I've come across it, I've just coded it another way (always longer).

My problem has always occurred within a for loop when variables I wish to use within a function expression (within the loop) are changing. It's very difficult for me to describe so here's a snippet from my project:

```
var exportList = [
    ['getmarkets', 'getcurrencies', 'getticker', 'getmarketsummaries',
    'getmarketsummary', 'getorderbook', 'getmarkethistory'],
    ['buylimit', 'selllimit', 'cancel', 'getopenorders'],
    ['getbalances', 'getbalance', 'getdepositaddress', 'withdraw',
    'getorder', 'getorderhistory', 'getwithdrawalhistory', 'getdeposithistory']
];

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < exportList.length; i1++) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < exportList[i1].length; i2++) {

        var ext = exportList[i1][i2];
        var subExt = '';

        if (i1 === 0) subExt = '/public/';
        else if (i1 === 1) subExt = '/market/';
        else if (i1 === 2) subExt = '/account/';

        module.exports[ext] = function (options) {
            options.ext = subExt + ext;
            sendRequest(options);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue lies within the anonymous function where I wish to use the values of `subExt` and `ext`. By the time the function is called though, the loop has caused the two variables to be assigned different values. I would like the function to use the values that the two variables had when the function was *created*.

I have tried many different ways in coming up with a solution. The most recent and closest being this:

```
module.exports[ext] = new Function(['options'], 
    `options.ext = "${subExt + ext}";
    (${sendRequest})(options);`
);
```

`sendRequest()` is a normal function, global in the module. The only reason this doesn't work is because this `Function()` constructor seems to create an isolated VM, `sendRequest()` calls another global function which it cannot access because of this. However, even if this did work I would be looking for an alternative because it's ugly as hell.

*Extra/potentially useless:* I've also tried it like this:

```
module.exports[ext] = function (options) {
    options.ext = this.subExt + this.ext;
    sendRequest(options);
}

module.exports[ext].subExt = subExt;
module.exports[ext].ext = ext;
```

But `this` seems to be `undefined`.

Please ask any questions if you don't understand! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Used `let` when declaring `ext` and `subExt` instead. Thanks @lilezek for that.